# Easy way to extract EXIF data in PowerShell?

Tags: image, date, powershell, exif

I've been looking at various methods that I can extract EXIF data using PowerShell, but I have so far seen that it is quite convoluted.
Some [here](http://blog.cincura.net/233463-renaming-files-based-on-exif-data-in-powershell/) and [here](https://chrisjwarwick.wordpress.com/2011/11/08/modify-date-taken-values-on-photos-with-powershell-the-update-exifdatetaken-script-cmdlet-2/).

I am looking for a (relatively) simple method to extract basic EXIF data using powershell, so that I can use it natively.

In particular, I am particularly interested in the **Date Taken** property and I am trying to find a method I can run this through **Get-Date**, and customise the formatting for my own needs.
Something like:

```
$exifdatetaken = $mypicture.'Date taken' | Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd-HHmmss
```

Does anyone know if there is a way to do this natively in PowerShell?

Comment: I don't know of a direct PowerShell command line tool, but I've written the .NET library [MetadataExtractor](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor-dotnet) that extracts metadata from image and movie files. You could write a PowerShell interface quite easily.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm looking for something native within the script itself, maybe something I could run in a small function, but I will look into this at it looks very interesting and useful. Thanks anyway. :)

Answer (score 4):

The reason that extracting EXIF metadata is generally so convoluted is because *image* metadata is stored as part of the file content (as opposed to *file* metadata, which is stored and indexed by the operating system separately from the file). Add to this the fact that EXIF is an extensible format which manufacturers often use (and abuse) to store data in proprietary formats, and the landscape can get confusing very quickly.

Both of the references you linked to use `[System.Drawing]` classes from the GDI+ Win32 API, which exposes more than 200 image properties, more than one of which might reflect the datetime a picture was taken. They both also hard code for a single property `36867 (0x9003)` which is the `PropertyTagExifDTOrig` value.

It's fairly simple to leverage the `[System.Drawing.Bitmap]` class to expose all of the available metadata, e.g.:

```
$path   = 'C:\my\images\Canon.jpg'
$bitmap = [System.Drawing.Bitmap]::new($path)
$bitmap.PropertyItems
```

Which will give a set of results like this:

```
   Id  Len Type Value
   --  --- ---- -----
  271    6    2 {67, 97, 110, 111, 110, 0}
  272   24    2 {67, 97, 110, 111, 110, 32, 69, 79, 83, 32…}
  274    2    3 {1, 0}
  282    8    5 {180, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}
  283    8    5 {180, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}
  296    2    3 {2, 0}
  306   20    2 {50, 48, 48, 51, 58, 49, 50, 58, 48, 52…}
  531    2    3 {1, 0}
33434    8    5 {4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}
33437    8    5 {14, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}
34855    2    3 {100, 0}
36864    4    7 {48, 50, 50, 49}
# etc.
```

That was the easy part. Getting something useful from this data is where it gets tricky. The `Id` references a [property tag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.propertyitem.id?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) to tell you which property you're looking at. The `Value` is an array of bytes that will need to be decoded into a meaningful value (which itself may be either a one or two step process). To know how to decode the bytes you need to look at the `Type` value which can be used to look up the [data type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.propertyitem.type?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#system-drawing-imaging-propertyitem-type). Once you've decoded the bytes, you may be left with:

- a meaningful value (e.g. an ASCII string that contains the camera manufacturer's name)
- a value which is either a reference to a lookup in the [EXIF standard](https://cipa.jp/e/std/std-sec.html) (e.g. for Id 37383 (0x9207 PropertyTagExifMeteringMode), a value of 0 means 'Unknown', 1 means 'Average', and so on), or that needs some additional calculation to get to a meaningful value
- an unknown value that can be decoded from some external reference (e.g. [ExifTool's list of tags](https://exiftool.org/TagNames/EXIF.html))
- an unknown value that can't be decoded (or that needs the originating software to decode)

For example, to get the date and time the image was created (an ASCII string) using Id 306 (0x0132 PropertyTagDateTime) would be something like:

```
$pi        = $bitmap.GetPropertyItem(306)
$ascii     = [System.Text.ASCIIEncoding]::new()
$piDecoded = $ascii.GetString($pi.Value[0..$($pi.Len-2)]) # trim off the trailing null terminator
$piDecoded
$piDecoded.GetType().FullName
```

Which returns e.g.:

```
2022:06:11 13:25:36
System.String
```

You could then either manipulate this directly into the format you want, or parse it and send it to Get-Date to get a DateTime object.

Another example, to get the ISO for an image (a SHORT (UInt16) type) using Id 34855 (0x8827 PropertyTagExifISOSpeed):

```
$pi        = $bitmap.GetPropertyItem(34855)
$piDecoded = [System.BitConverter]::ToUInt16($pi.Value,0)
$piDecoded
$piDecoded.GetType().FullName
```

Which returns e.g.:

```
100
System.UInt16
```

And so on.

I had wanted to solve exactly the same problem, primarily to do a mass renaming of images in my personal archive, but also to have a simple way to filter for images based on, for example, image orientation, which I built into a PowerShell module. You can see the specific implementation of the logic I described above in [this](https://github.com/nmbell/PSReadExif/blob/main/functions/Get-ExifData.ps1) function.

Comment: Thanks so much for this explanation.
I just about gave up on this project a while ago, but I have wanted to get it back due to more image archiving coming up. I'll take a look at the function link you posted.