# Powershell - How to rename a set of files of different extensions by Date?

Tags: powershell, image, sorting

First off, I don't actually know Powershell. I've just cobbled together a possible answer to my problem through other people's similar issues.

I want to take a set of photos and videos and have them sorted by Date/Date Taken and rename to add a set of sequential numbers at the front of the file names. IE "0001 - OriginalName"

This is what my latest attempt was but I don't actually know what it's doing except not what I want. (I know that -WhatIf doesn't actually run the commands so that's not my issue)

```
$count = 1
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users\miste\OneDrive\Desktop\Finalized Seattle Pictures' -File |
Sort-Object CreationTime |
Rename-Item -NewName {'{0:D4} - {1}' -f $script:count++, $_ } -WhatIf
```

The images are taken from two different iPhones so the IMG_#### is going to be all over the place but hopefully that doesn't matter in the end, I just need the files in this order but with the four digit sorting number at the front.

Files needing sorting:

[image: Files needing sorting]

Result of the Code:

[image: Result of the Code]

New code from jfrmilner: `Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users\miste\OneDrive\Desktop\Finalized Seattle Pictures' -File | Sort-Object CreationTime | Select-Object Name, CreationTime -First 5`

[Result of new code:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjQqp.png)

Comment: so what's wrong with he names generated by that code?

Comment: right, your code looks fine its unclear what you actually want as a result

Comment: I've added an image of what the code results to and it looks like it's still just sorting by name and since there's two different sets of iPhone photos, the names aren't in the right order that I need.

Comment: its still unclear whats the order that you need.

Comment: I suspect you want to sort these by Exif DateTaken and rename.  You could use [Get-ExifDateTaken](https://chrisjwarwick.wordpress.com/2011/10/31/reading-and-changing-exif-photo-times-with-powershell/) or [Easy way to extract EXIF data in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34913250/easy-way-to-extract-exif-data-in-powershell) to get this info. (This will replace `CreationTime`)

Comment: Santiago, I need the pictures in the order shown in the second image but instead of the prefix numbers being 0704,0703,0702,0548,0549 I need them to be 0001,0002,0003, etc. I'm sure I need to sort by descending somewhere in the code but even still, I have no idea what it's actually sorting by at this time.

Comment: jfrmilner, unless I'm not understanding part of my problem or the information you've supplied, I don't think I need to change the time at which these pictures were taken as they're currently accurate. I just want my set of images to be properly renamed in order of their current time taken.

Comment: I didn't suggest changing the time, only how you're sorting. If you remove `Rename-Item` do the files list in the console in the order you are expecting? (Top picture, right?). If they don't then `CreationTime` is not the date property you're looking for.

Comment: Your code results don't make sense if those timestamps are correct. Their current filenames are already in timestamp order, anyway. But why does the file at 03:10 get a higher number (0704) than the one at 04:41 (0702)?

Comment: jfrmilner, I apologize for needing clarification but I'm not sure what exactly to remove. I tried removing just "Rename-Item", the entire line following "Rename-Item", and the entire line following "Rename-Item" with "-WhatIf" at the end of the second line as three separate attempts. Nothing happened with any of the attempts and just removing "Rename-Item" threw an error.

Comment: Mark, I have two iPhones that took pictures from this trip. Phone A has IMG numbers running from 3871 to 4466 and Phone B has IMG numbers running from 1948 to 2156. I want all the files from Phone A + Phone B to sort and rename by time. I have no idea how the code is even sorting... Once I run the code and order by Name so it goes 0001-0718 I find that date is sorted in three different sections. First section is almost all of Phone Bs files running from 6/10-6/16, section 2 is almost all Phone A files doing the same, and section three is about 50 files from 6/10 only.

Comment: Run command `Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users\miste\OneDrive\Desktop\Finalized Seattle Pictures' -File | Sort-Object CreationTime | Select-Object Name, CreationTime -First 5` and append the text output to the question (not a new comment). This will not rename the files and will help us understand the issue.

Comment: Sorry it took me until today to get this done. It looks like CreationTime isn't what we want as it's the time the photos were copied and duplicated to different locations. I really appreciate all the help you're giving on this. If this is becoming too much you really don't have to continue helping.